# Issue with Swift 5.7 existentials

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, existential-type

I recently converted some of my code which originally used Type-Erasure to use the new Swift 5.7 `any` existential.
However, I'm getting some issues when trying to use the `any` keyword with already implemented generic types.

I'm running this on **Xcode 14 Beta 2** (which has Implicitly Opened Existentials).

Here is an example:

```swift
protocol Provider<Value> {
    associatedtype Value
    
    func get() -> Value
}

struct S {
    var stringProvider: any Provider<String>
}
```

Here is a very simple struct `S` which has a member `stringProvider`. I use the `any` keyword here instead of making `any Provider<String>` generic because I would like to be able to reassign `stringProvider` to a different value later on (which has a different type).

```swift
struct ProviderView<P: Provider>: View {
    let provider: P
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(describing: type(of: provider.get())))
    }
}
```

Now here I have a `ProviderView` SwiftUI struct, which takes in a `Provider` and does stuff with it.

```swift
struct DummyProvider: Provider {
    typealias Value = String
    
    func get() -> String {
        "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

And this is just a dummy `Provider` implementation which just returns a string.

This all works fine, the problem comes when I try to use `ProviderView` with an existential `any`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let s = S(stringProvider: DummyProvider())
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            ProviderView(provider: s.stringProvider) // This is the erroring line
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying `Type 'any Provider<String>' cannot conform to 'Provider'`.

I think I know why, it's because `ProviderView` cannot have an `any` existential as a generic argument.

**My question is:** Is there any way around this, without going back to type erasure? Am I doing something really badly wrong? Keep in mind that I need to be able to reassign `S.stringProvider` to a `Provider` of a different type.

Comment: We've got explicit reply from Apple engineer that `any` (ie. anything result in `any View`) does not work for SwiftUI "mechanics". See this thread https://twitter.com/asperi_se/status/1543294437979217920?s=20&t=gIAPoC6fHj_l0P8F_ETLWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `body` needs to be some specific type, so ProviderView needs to be some specific type (since `body` relies on that type). It can't change at runtime. So ProviderView can't be generic over its Provider if that's going to change at runtime.

That means that `ProviderView.provider` needs to be `any Provider`, not generic:

```
struct ProviderView: View {
    let provider: any Provider

    var body: some View {
        Text(String(describing: type(of: provider.get())))
    }
}
```

So that part is expected.

The problem you'll run into is that [the current runtime can't quite handle this yet](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-se-0353-features-constrained-existential-types/58258/3), and you'll get an error later:

```
// Runtime support for parameterized protocol types is only available in iOS 99.0.0 or newer
ProviderView(provider: s.stringProvider)
```

I do expect this to improve in later betas, though I encourage you to open a Feedback to track it.

Comment: Ok, this makes so much more sense to me now. Thank you so much! I think I'll stick with type erasers though.

Answer (score 1):

`any Provider` is an existential, and existentials being some kind of boxes, don't conform to the protocol inside the box, thus you see the error.

If you're not keen on having `ProviderView` generic, you can add a custom initializer that uses `some` - this represents the actual value conforming to the protocol, so the compiler is happy.

```swift
struct ProviderView: View {
    let provider: any Provider
    
    init(provider: some Provider) {
        self.provider = provider
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(describing: type(of: provider.get())))
    }
}
```

Though with a generic view like this, there's not much you can accomplish with the `provider`.