# Why do you need type erasure in this case?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-erasure

I have a simple protocol `Provider` like this:

```
protocol Provider {
    func get() -> String
}
```

And a struct `S` that has an existential `Provider` as a field:

```
struct S {
    var provider: any Provider
}
```

I also have a view `ProviderView` like this:

```
struct ProviderView<P: Provider>: View {
    let provider: P
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(provider.get())
    }
}
```

And an implementation of `Provider` like so:

```
struct DummyProvider: Provider {
    func get() -> String {
        "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Now the problem comes when I try to use `ProviderView` passing in `S.provider`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let s = S(provider: DummyProvider())
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            ProviderView(provider: s.provider) // This is the erroring line.
        }
    }
}
```

An error occurs:

```
Type 'any Provider' cannot conform to 'Provider'
```

Now this is expected, as described excellently in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862265/16889355), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/16889355).

The reason why this code doesn't work is because the `View`'s `body` property is fixed at runtime, therefore `ProviderView` being generic over a **dynamic** type isn't allowed.

The thing is, a super thin type erasing `AnyProvider` struct fixes this issue:

```
struct AnyProvider: Provider {
    let erased: any Provider
    
    func get() -> String {
        return erased.get()
    }
}
```

Now `ProviderView` has a concrete type to be generic over.

However, you can see that `AnyProvider` itself literally just stores an `any Provider` member variable. The size of `AnyProvider` should still be unknown.

I think if the problem were that the size of `any Provider` isn't known at runtime, then why does using `AnyProvider` solve this? After all, it just contains a single field which has an unknown size at runtime.

So my question is: Why isn't Swift able to synthesize a similar wrapper? **What is the difference between using `any Provider` and a struct that contains a single field of type `any Provider`?**

What prevents Swift from allowing you to use `any Provider` vs `AnyProvider`?

**How is `AnyProvider` any more concrete than `any Provider` other than its type?**

I really would like to know if I'm missing something.

P.S: I'm using Xcode 14 Beta 3 with Swift 5.7.

Comment: This is how Swift works currently, it distinguishes a type itself (any generic Something) and a box, containing the type (the Something itself). At WWDC22 they promised us, it's not going to be a problem anymore after Swift 5.7: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110354/

Comment: @lazarevzubov But I'm actually currently using Swift 5.7 right now (with Xcode 14 Beta 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your `ProviderView` with `any Provider`

```
struct ProviderView: View {
    let provider: any Provider
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(provider.get())
    }
}
```